# Access several columns in an array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm new to python and numpy. Suppose I have an array `A = np.random.rand(10,100)` , how do i access some of its columns easily?

In `Matlab` I would write something like `B = A(:,[2,4,6:10,50:80])`. What is the equivalent of this line of code in Python?

I've looked at the examples in http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users.html  but none of them answer my question.

Comment: See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html, and `numpy.r_[]`

Comment: Well, one way would be to use range to simulate the colon operation and then just index into cols : `A[:,np.hstack((2,4,range(6,10+1),range(50,80+1)))]`.

Comment: `@Divakar` I've actually also tried this way, but I believed there must be some method simpler than it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `Benjamin` suggested, `np.r_` handles an expression like this nicely

```
In [1329]: np.r_[2,4,6:10,50:80]
Out[1329]: 
array([ 2,  4,  6,  7,  8,  9, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60,
       61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77,
       78, 79])
```

which can be used as:

```
B = A[:, np.r_[2,4,6:10,50:80]]
```

`r_` expands the slices into ranges and concatenates everything together, as in `Divakar's` comment.

Comment: Ah didn't know that colon could be used within `np.r_[]`, nice!

Comment: There are more features in `r_` (and `c_`) than most of us need.  I've never had to use the first argument string.  The `j` step is just a cute way of using `linspace` instead of `arange`.  If features are useful, great.  But if you don't understand them, don't worry.

Comment: This is exactly the information I'm looking for. I believe the link `Benjamin` provides is a good knowledge base. For now it seems overwhelming to me. I'm still trying to understand `r_[]` and `c_[]`